# Logging Google mail in Google sheet, Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

HELP! I’m using a script I basically cribbed from Tom Woodward at Bionice Teaching to record email messages in a spreadsheet. 
http://bionicteaching.com/auto-logging-email-via-google-script/
I need to add a column that collects any labels that have been attached to the messages. I need to get this done for my work, but I'm brand new to Google Apps Script and really need someone to hold my hand... Essentially doing it for me, then teaching me what it was you did. I really appreciate any help you can give me in any case. Thanks
Here is what I’m using:

```
function myFunction() {

//this is just the stuff that recognizes what spreadsheet you're in
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheets = ss.getSheets();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("data"); //gets the right sheet

//this chunk gets the date info  
 var today = new Date();
 var dd = today.getDate()-1;
 var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0 DO NOT FORGET THIS
 var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 var yesterday = yyyy + '/' + mm + '/' + dd;

//****************************************************  
//searches your GMail for emails written after yesterday
  var query = "after:" + yesterday;

  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  Logger.log('threads len ' + threads.length);

  Logger.log(query);

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    Logger.log(messages);    
    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
       var supportStats = [];

//here's where you decide what parts of the email you want
      var from = messages[m].getFrom(); //from field
      Logger.log(from);
      var time = messages[m].getDate();//date field
      Logger.log(time);
      var subject = messages[m].getSubject();//subject field
      Logger.log(subject);
      var body = messages[m].getPlainBody();//body field
      Logger.log(body);
      var mId = messages[m].getId();//id field to create the link later

      var mYear = time.getFullYear();
      var mMonth = time.getMonth()+1;
      var mDay = time.getDate();
      var messageDate = mYear + '/' + mMonth + '/' + mDay;
      Logger.log('msg date ' + messageDate);

//decides what found emails match yesterday's date and push them to an array to write to the spreadsheet
      if (messageDate === yesterday) {
      supportStats.push(from);
      supportStats.push(time);
      supportStats.push(subject);
      supportStats.push(body);
      supportStats.push('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId); //build the URL to the email
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(supportStats); //writes to the spreadsheet
      }
    }

  }          

}
```

Here is the results I'm getting... Perfect!
Except I'd like one more column that adds the labels that are on each message. How do I do that?
[spreatsheet results of Google Apps script mail->sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2yfy.png)

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? Can you provide the issues of your current script? For example, if the result is not what you want and/or if error occurs, please show them.

Comment: I believe labels are attached to threads, not messages. So you could use `messages[m].getThread().getLabels()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var labels = threads[i].getLabels();
```

[GmailThread::getLabels()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getLabels())

GmailThread has labels, not GmailMessage. It returns an array of labels. Maybe use:

```
var labelsString = "";
var labelArray = []
for each (var label in labels)
{
  labelArray.push(label.getName());
}
if (labelArray.length > 0)
{
  labelsString = labelArray.join(','); 
}
```

to insert into the row of the spreadsheet.

[GmailLabel::getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label#getName())

Comment: Use of the `for each (var ... in...)` syntax should not be recommended. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in Consider instead something using array#map or array#reduce, e.g. `var labelsToPrint = thread.getLabels().map(function (label) { return label.getName(); }).join(", ");`

Comment: Can someone show me exactly how to use this fix? I'm not sure where exactly to add this code.